Can Mac Pro 2019 run Apple Thunderbolt Display 2011?
Can a Mac Pro 2019 or later run Apple Thunderbolt Display 2011? I used them with a Mac Pro 2013 though.
I haven't bought a Mac Pro 2019 yet, so if there's a specific configuration or video card I need to have for support, please advise.
I have been looking at this reference as well.

The displays in question.


You should be able to use the display with the newer Mac. You will probably have to purchase Apple's Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) to Thunderbolt 2 Adapter.


You can find documentation to support this answer by following a link first posted with the reference given in your question. From this reference, there is the link Adapters for the Thunderbolt 3 or USB-C port on your Mac. Below is a screenshot taken from this website.


Thanks for the answer. I have 3 Thunderbolt displays, and I see two Thunderbolt ports in the picture. https://i.sstatic.net/FyLH0CiV.webp.
I assume I buy two adapters and must daisy chain the 3rd one? Please confirm.

I am not sure if you can daisy chain. There is are two more Thunderbolt ports on the top of the machine. See this picture.

After comparing your picture with the specs, I see there is a video card with a HDMI port and 4 thunderbolt ports. So my count is 8 total thunderbolt ports.

This is a nice website. It offers more pictures and a video.
